# Deleting key/value from list of dictionaries using lambda and map

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have a list of dictionaries that have the same keys within eg:

```
[{k1:'foo', k2:'bar', k3...k4....}, {k1:'foo2', k2:'bar2', k3...k4....}, ....]
```

I'm trying to delete k1 from all dictionaries within the list.

I tried

```
map(lambda x: del x['k1'], list)
```

but that gave me a syntax error. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

lambda bodies are only expressions, not statements like `del`.

If you *have* to use map and lambda, then:

```
map(lambda d: d.pop('k1'), list_of_d)
```

A for loop is probably clearer:

```
for d in list_of_d:
    del d['k1']
```

Comment: wont that just give me a list of 'k1's? pop returns the value that gets removed i believe.

Comment: It sounds like you don't really want `map`.  You are not trying to compute a list of values from another list.  You are trying to act on a list.  Use the for loop instead.

Comment: And BTW, `map` will produce the list of deleted values, but you can ignore the value returned from `map` if you want.

Comment: sorry misunderstood you - just tried it and yes the list has k1 removed. will take your suggestion and go with the list.

Comment: Heads up `map` returns *map object* in Python 3, not a list, therefore **lambda will not be executed** unless consumed.

Comment: I think you also need to check if a key exists in the dictionary before removing it.